# How can i save or bookmark a cypher query in the Neo4J browser?

Tags: browser, neo4j

when i save my cypher scripts under saved scripts in the Neo4J browser, and log off for the day, when i return and sign back on, the scripts are gone and I cannot retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j saved scripts are stored in the browser's cache. Any time your browser's cache is cleared, the saved scripts will disappear.

You could register for Neo4j's Browser Sync feature that will use one of your social media accounts to authenticate you and will then store several things, including your saved queries, in the cloud. This would allow you, regardless of which browser you're using or which Neo4j database you're working with, to have access to your saved queries.

Read more here: https://neo4j.com/whats-new-in-neo4j-3-0/

If you'd prefer not to do this, you could always just save your queries in an external (to Neo4j) text file and import/copy-paste them when you have the need for them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to favorite a cypher query, and then download it as a cypher file, and then later use it by dragging it to the browser in the new version 4.4 (but it was added before this version, not sure which one).